# FaceBook-Scraper (without API) works nicely - but Login Process failes some how

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping, python-requests, web-crawler

working on the getting to run the Facebook-Scraper (cf  https://github.com/kevinzg/facebook-scraper )

```
import facebook_scraper as fs

# get POST_ID from the URL of the post which can have the following structure:
# https://www.facebook.com/USER/posts/POST_ID
# https://www.facebook.com/groups/GROUP_ID/posts/POST_ID
POST_ID = "pfbid02NsuAiBU9o1ouwBrw1vYAQ7khcVXvz8F8zMvkVat9UJ6uiwdgojgddQRLpXcVBqYbl"

# number of comments to download -- set this to True to download all comments
MAX_COMMENTS = 100

# get the post (this gives a generator)
gen = fs.get_posts(
    post_urls=[POST_ID],
    options={"comments": MAX_COMMENTS, "progress": True}
)

# take 1st element of the generator which is the post we requested
post = next(gen)

# extract the comments part
comments = post['comments_full']

# process comments as you want...
for comment in comments:

    # e.g. ...print them
    print(comment)

    # e.g. ...get the replies for them
    for reply in comment['replies']:
        print(' ', reply)
```

i got back the following

```
LoginRequired                             Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-5-19c42c721928> in <cell line: 18>()
     16 
     17 # take 1st element of the generator which is the post we requested
---> 18 post = next(gen)
     19 
     20 # extract the comments part

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/facebook_scraper/facebook_scraper.py in get(self, url, **kwargs)
    940                     or response.url.startswith(utils.urljoin(FB_W3_BASE_URL, "login"))
    941                 ):
--> 942                     raise exceptions.LoginRequired(
    943                         "A login (cookies) is required to see this page"
    944                     )

LoginRequired: A login (cookies) is required to see this page
```

note: we have the options like the following:

**Optional parameters**

```
(For the get_posts function).

    group: group id, to scrape groups instead of pages. Default is None.
    pages: how many pages of posts to request, the first 2 pages may have no results, so try with a number greater than 2. Default is 10.
    timeout: how many seconds to wait before timing out. Default is 30.
    credentials: tuple of user and password to login before requesting the posts. Default is None.
    extra_info: bool, if true the function will try to do an extra request to get the post reactions. Default is False.
    youtube_dl: bool, use Youtube-DL for (high-quality) video extraction. You need to have youtube-dl installed on your environment. Default is False.
    post_urls: list, URLs or post IDs to extract posts from. Alternative to fetching based on username.
    cookies: One of:
        The path to a file containing cookies in Netscape or JSON format. You can extract cookies from your browser after logging into Facebook with an extension like Get cookies.txt LOCALLY or Cookie Quick Manager (Firefox). Make sure that you include both the c_user cookie and the xs cookie, you will get an InvalidCookies exception if you don't.
        A CookieJar
        A dictionary that can be converted to a CookieJar with cookiejar_from_dict
        The string "from_browser" to try extract Facebook cookies from your browser
    options: Dictionary of options. Set options={"comments": True} to extract comments, set options={"reactors": True} to extract the people reacting to the post. Both comments and reactors can also be set to a number to set a limit for the amount of comments/reactors to retrieve. Set options={"progress": True} to get a tqdm progress bar while extracting comments and replies. Set options={"allow_extra_requests": False} to disable making extra requests when extracting post data (required for some things like full text and image links). Set options={"posts_per_page": 200} to request 200 posts per page. The default is 4.
```

( cf https://github.com/kevinzg/facebook-scraper )

but the question is - how to arrange the login process

note: i am on google-colab:

Comment: to get a login you have to look at the options more precicely - i think that there are some certain processes needet. weather this will work on Google-Colab with ease - i do not know atm. But just have a closer look at the github-page whereas you may find more data regarding the login process.

Comment: u gotta give the credentais at first see here  ´´´credentials: tuple of user and password to login before requesting the posts. Default is None´´´
  At the moment i am  on a train - and cannot check this out - but plz do this check - you ought to give the tuple - and i guess that this is pretty important.

Comment: as the githubsite states - you re able to work with this tool in versatile mode: read: The get_profile function can extract information from a profile's about section. Pass in the account name or ID as the first parameter. Note that Facebook serves different information depending on whether you're logged in (cookies parameter), such as Date of birth and Gender. Usage:

well see ```from facebook_scraper import get_profile
get_profile("zuck") # Or get_profile("zuck", cookies="cookies.txt")``` not testet here atm. but afaik this looks good to me.  have a look at the manpage at github !

Comment: g' day, thanks for the reply and for all the hints and idea-sharing. Well i have been searching for a apropriate approach to do this fb-parser job: after searched quite a fair time - i found out that there not many options to take if you do not want to use the API: So i try to figure out how good this is: On the relevant list of repos on GitHub, one that seems to be popular, up to date & works well: https://github.com/kevinzg/facebook-scraper

Example CLI usage: ```pip install facebook-scraper
facebook-scraper --filename nintendo_page_posts.csv --pages 10 nintendo```
Thx for all so far !

Comment: Dude  just have a closer lookt: There’s a fork of that project. If you read the Github Issues people were having problems with the original fb scraper. 
So someone forked it and made some modifications. I would check out the fork. It’s promising and has been a starting point for some projects we are doing.
```https://github.com/moda20/facebook-scraper```: btw: see this one: This branch is 60 commits ahead of kevinzg/facebook-scraper:master.
awesome ... this is developed more sustainable: This is so great - i allways thougth that the kevin-scraper is the best out there but the moda20 is cool